# Why is the nucleus accumbens in that place?

Tags: neuroscience, zoology, brain, ornithology, ventricles

This description of where the nucleus accumbens is (Ac) says that it should be near the lateral ventricle, when it is quite clearly very far away? How is this?

> the region surrounding the tip of the lateral ventricle, at the ventromedial margin of the rostral pole of the medial striatum (MSt) in birds is marked as the nucleus accumbens
>
> > (from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2481519/)

Furthermore the lateral ventricle seems to be in very different places in both diagrams although they are both avian brains?

[image: img](https://avianbrain.org/papers/RevisedNomenclature.pdf figure 2)

[image: img2]
(https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2481519/ figure 1)

thank you for any help :)

Comment: Please add references for the diagrams and quoted text.

Comment: references added :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ventricle looks in a different place simply because the first image is a transverse section whereas the second one is a sagittal section. 
In the sagittal version the striatum looks very far from the ventricle because it is a quite lateral slide, more medially it would look closer to it as it does in the first figure you show.

Here you can see a representation showing also a more medial transverse section.
source: Vertebrate brains and evolutionary connectomics: on the origins of the mammalian ‘neocortex’. Harvey J. Karten. (2015) DOI: 10.1098/rstb.2015.0060

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification that was so useful :)

Comment: So in the sagittal section diagram, would you still say the Ac surrounds the tip of the lateral ventricle?

Comment: It is not visible in that figure, but is not false.